# Is there a way to change the window size?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

It's a simple question, and I hope to get a simple answer.

**Is it possible to resize the game's window? If so, how?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no option to change the size of the window arbitrarily, although you can make it fullscreen.  There are several fullscreen options, which involve different methods of scaling and handling aspect ratio differences.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by editing the settings.ini file.

Set: `manual`, `windowed` and `stretched` to `1`

Then you can set `screen_X` and `screen_Y` to whatever size you want.

For example:

```
manual=1
screen_x=640
screen_y=360
windowed=1
stretched=1
```

Answer (score -2):

In settings, try putting `Fullscreen=1`